# Access denied finding property "acodec.video.buflogging" on HMD Global phones

Tags: android, audio, video, android-mediacodec

I am using [INDExOS/media-for-mobile](https://github.com/INDExOS/media-for-mobile) for ovelaying video in my android app.

It is working fine at Motorola, Samsung, Nexus and Pixel Devices. But I am getting following error in case of HMD Global(Nokia) Devices,

```
Access denied finding property "acodec.video.buflogging"
W/MediaCodec_loop: type=1400 audit(0.0:2659): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:mtk_em_video_log_acodec_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=6644 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mtk_em_video_log_acodec_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you got the solution ?

Comment: No, But I found that It was happening due to video recorded on HMD Global(Nokia) is in .3gp format. This error is not coming in case of mp4 video.